# patch: **** can't create temporary file permission denied

Tags: docker, patch, openwrt, apfs, mktemp

I'm trying to build OpenWRT in a docker container. This works fine on windows host platforms and on Linux host platforms but on a MacOS host (after moving the build folder on the host to a case-sensitive volume) I get the following error after running `make world V=s`:

```
mkdir -p /workspaces/MyProject/OpenWRT/dl
SHELL= flock /workspaces/MyProject/OpenWRT/tmp/.tar-1.34.tar.xz.flock -c '      /workspaces/MyProject/OpenWRT/scripts/download.pl "/workspaces/MyProject/OpenWRT/dl" "tar-1.34.tar.xz" "63bebd26879c5e1eea4352f0d03c991f966aeb3ddeb3c7445c902568d5411d28" "" "@GNU/tar"    '
+ curl -f --connect-timeout 20 --retry 5 --location https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/gnu/tar/tar-1.34.tar.xz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 2173k  100 2173k    0     0   436k      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--  523k
. /workspaces/MyProject/OpenWRT/include/shell.sh; xzcat /workspaces/MyProject/OpenWRT/dl/tar-1.34.tar.xz | tar -C /workspaces/MyProject/OpenWRT/build_dir/host/tar-1.34/.. -xf -
[ ! -d ./src/ ] || cp -fpR ./src/* /workspaces/MyProject/OpenWRT/build_dir/host/tar-1.34
 
Applying ./patches/100-symlink-force-root-name.patch using plaintext: 
patch: **** Can't create temporary file /workspaces/MyProject/OpenWRT/tmp/ppA9ZnfY : Permission denied
Patch failed!  Please fix ./patches/100-symlink-force-root-name.patch!
make[3]: *** [Makefile:37: /workspaces/MyProject/OpenWRT/build_dir/host/tar-1.34/.preparedf569e8812277cec47eb2e48349e7e46f_6664517399ebbbc92a37c5bb081b5c53] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/workspaces/MyProject/OpenWRT/tools/tar'
time: tools/tar/compile#2.46#0.44#7.62
    ERROR: tools/tar failed to build.
make[2]: *** [tools/Makefile:168: tools/tar/compile] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/workspaces/MyProject/OpenWRT'
make[1]: *** [tools/Makefile:164: /workspaces/MyProject/OpenWRT/staging_dir/host/stamp/.tools_compile_yyynyynnyyyynyyyyyynyynnyynyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyynynyyyyyyyy] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/workspaces/MyProject/OpenWRT'
make: *** [/workspaces/MyProject/OpenWRT/include/toplevel.mk:230: world] Error 2
vscode@3161c8b1fe01:/workspaces/MyProject/OpenWRT$ ls -al tmp/pp*
ls: cannot access 'tmp/ppA9ZnfY': Permission denied
vscode@3161c8b1fe01:/workspaces/MyProject/OpenWRT$
```

Now the temp file `ppA9ZnfY` is created in the OpenWRT/tmp directory, but the file is corrupted, i.e. when I ls on the host system's terminal I get this:

```
----------    1 user  staff         0 Nov 27 19:14 ppA9ZnfY
```

Opening the document info in finder shows this:

[image]

Does anyone know what can cause this issue and how to solve it?